# How can I make a web page reflow with CSS Grid as screen sizes change?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need help reflowing a web page using CSS Grid as the screen size changes. I want to achieve the following:

1. The main column should have a minimum width of 400px;
2. The sidebar should have a maximum width of the content area (the image);
3. When I resize the width of the screen, I want the sidebar to drop below the main column (or something like that).

My experiment is available [here](https://thimbleprojects.org/pauljacobson/301284). I haven't pasted all the code in the interests of keeping this question manageable. I'd appreciate help with the CSS code.

My focus is this part of the CSS:

```
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-gap: 10px;
grid-template-columns: minmax(400px, 2fr)
  repeat(auto-fill, max-content);
grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
grid-auto-flow: inherit;
grid-template-areas: 
  "hd hd"
  "mn as"
  "mn ...."
  "ft ft";
background-color: lightsalmon;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Well you would use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for this one.

Comment: Thanks, although I've seen this done without using a media query. Take a look at this example: https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/zwPEoX

Comment: I think that example is using [flexbox](https://envato.com/blog/css3-flexbox/)

Comment: Here you can see some examples: [Better, Simpler Grid Systems](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/)

Comment: Please post enough code in the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: How wide do you want the sidebar to be when it drops down? Full screen width?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted: [Header, as many as will fit, footer](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/zwPEoX) the grid is reflowing because of minmax() settings. minmax is a very simple if statement actually. In case of columns:

```
function(min, max){
   if(this.width >= min){
      this.width = max;
   else{
      this.width = min;
   }
}
```

that is the basic idea of it. It uses the max value untill it reaches the min value, and then it uses that. Cells will go a row further if there is no space after them.

For the issues you want to solve you need to use a media query as pointed out by Cyclonecode. You can't switch the position of cells without media queries, especially if you defined a certain amount of rows and named the areas.